# Ruby on Rails select between start of day and middle day from lessons

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello im developing an app for a gym and in the stats section i got stucked in this query. I need to select all the lessons that starts between the start of the day and 13:00 from the database and then count them but i havent figure out how to make the sentence. the closest i did was this, How can i select all the lessons that starts before 13:00 of all month togheter? thanks

```
@lessons_morning    =   Lesson.where(start_date: (beginning_of_day)..Time.beginning_of_day + 13.hours,updated_at: (Time.now.beginning_of_month)..Time.now.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing both date and time in the same column, I would do it like this:

First, let's query for all lessons in the current month:

```
# use Time.zone.now instead of Time.now to use the timezone specified in your application config
@lessons = Lesson.where(
  start_date: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now.end_of_month
)
```

Then, let's only find lessons which start between 0:00 and 13:00:

```
@lessons.select do |lesson| 
  start_hour = lesson.start_date.strftime('%H%M').to_i
  start_hour <= 1300
}
```